# Tight upper bound on the function of expected value

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

Let $R$ be a positive integer, $\mathcal{X}$ be the sample space and $x \in \mathcal{X}$ be an event of the sample space; $P(x)$ denotes the probability of occurrence of event $x$. The problem is to upper bound the following expression:

$$
\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}x(P(x))^{\frac{1}{R}},
$$
in terms of $$\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}}xP(x).$$

Is it possible to get a tighter bound for the expression?